# Storybook 7 with Monorepo and React issue

Tags: reactjs, storybook, monorepo

I just created a new react app with `npx create-react-app` and typescript and I created some workspaces with yarn 3.6.0 with

```
"workspaces": [
    "packages/*/*"
],
```

Later I added storybook to the project using `npx storybook@latest init`.
Running `storybook dev -p 6006` works well with the stories loaded from root folder `src/stories`. But placing the stories inside the packages ( ex packages/react/spinner/src/Spinner.stories.tsx ) I get this error

```
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/@storybook/source-loader/dist/index.js
 * ./node_modules/unplugin/dist/webpack/loaders/load.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import { Spinner } from './Spinner';
| import { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
> const meta: Meta<typeof Spinner> = {parameters: {
|   "storySource": {
|     "source": "import { Spinner } from './Spinner';\nimport { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';\nconst meta: Meta<typeof Spinner> = {\n  component: Spinner\n};\nexport default meta;\ntype Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;\nexport const Primary: Story = {\n  args: {}\n};\nPrimary.parameters = {\n  ...Primary.parameters,\n  docs: {\n    ...Primary.parameters?.docs,\n    source: {\n      originalSource: \"{\\n  args: {}\\n}\",\n      ...Primary.parameters?.docs?.source\n    }\n  }\n};",
```

my `main.ts` in `.storyboock` folder is the following:

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from '@storybook/react-webpack5';
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: [
    '../packages/react/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '../src/**/*.mdx',
    '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    '@storybook/addon-storysource',
    '@storybook/addon-mdx-gfm',
  ],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-webpack5',
    options: {},
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag',
  },
  staticDirs: ['../public'],
};

export default config;
```

How could i fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: I'm also having this same problem in my monorepo. Did you find a solution? What worked for me was setting a `babel.config.json` with some presets and removing `@storybook/preset-create-react-app` from the add-ons list. It seems that `@storybook/preset-create-react-app` won't work as expected in monorepos.